# How can I hide bootstrap modals based on screen width?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using the modal a site on and cannot get it to hide on mobile.

I have tried @media to hide the modal's parent div, but the background shows up and everything breaks.

There must be a simple way to conditionally turn this off that I am missing. Thanks!!

Comment: A modal is launched upon clicking something, why not hide the button that triggers it with a "hidden-xs" class on it. This is if you want to hide on viewport widths that are under 768px, if you want to actually disable on mobile, you'd use js to sniff whether or not it's a touch device. That's a different answer.

Comment: This modal happens on page load so unfortunately I can't hide a button. The touch device solution would be interesting to see, do you have a link to some documentation that would explain more? It won't answer the question but I would like to read about it.

Comment: I use this script: https://coderwall.com/p/egbgdw/detect-touch-events-on-all-major-mobile-platforms

Comment: `    if ($('html').hasClass('no-touch')) {
        // code here that launches the modal onload only on non-touch devices
    }`

Comment: Why not detect the window width with jquery. You can find plenty of examples of detecting on resize and load if <=767px then not show else show it.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the ideas for the future. I was able to dig through the CSS and create a bootstrap-specific answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to dig through the chrome inspector and solve this by hiding elements based on bootstrap modal classes and IDs.

**note:** This could cause issues if you try to initiate another Bootstrap modal since it will have these CSS classes.  It might be better to find a javascript solution if you don't control the whole stack.

The modal is composed of these three things. If you disable them, you disable the modal:

`/* Hide a modal below a specific width */
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
        .modal-backdrop { 
            display: none !important;
        }
        #myModalDiv {
            display: none !important;
        }
        .modal-dialog {
            display: none !important;
        }
    }`

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good answer. I was recently exposed to a bug where Bootstrap's JavaScript would overflow its stack when two modals were on the screen. So simply hiding the modal like this might cause issues if you pop up another one.

Comment: If you are using these classes in multiple places on a single page you should definitely not do exactly this.  I would recommend building out a second set of these same classes that can be applied conditionally (during @media) to the modal you wish to hide.  This might still be too complex. I definitely see why what you mention will cause problems. Maybe it would be a better route to allow multiple modals in bootstrap.